# Cannot rpm uninstall packages on AIX

Tags: rpm, uninstallation, aix, gettext, libiconv

it seems to be a dependency loop...

```
# rpm -e libiconv-1.15-1.ppc
error: Failed dependencies:
        libiconv.a(libiconv.so.2) is needed by (installed) gettext-0.19.8.1-1.ppc
        libiconv >= 1.15-1 is needed by (installed) gettext-0.19.8.1-1.ppc
# rpm -e gettext-0.19.8.1-1.ppc
error: Failed dependencies:
        gettext is needed by (installed) libiconv-1.15-1.ppc
```

gettext-0.19.8.1-1 depends on libiconv-1.15-1 and libiconv-1.15-1 depends on gettext-0.19.8.1-1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Zsigmond Lőrinczy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4844822/zsigmond-l%c5%91rinczy) commented, uninstall both at the same time:

```
rpm -e libiconv-1.15-1.ppc gettext-0.19.8.1-1.ppc
```